# Need to pass empty slice in [] this format and not as ""

Tags: arrays, json, go, slice

I have a api with one attribute of body as

type Reg struct{
Env          []string   `json:"env"`
}

while calling the api I need to pass value of "env" as optional parameter.
i.e.
in this format `env: []`, and not as `env: ""` 
Can anyone help pls.

I have tried using len(env)==0 but it take both "" and [] as empty.
I have also tried using reflect.ValueOf(Reg.Env).Kind() == reflect.Slice to differentiate between "" and [] but it takes both the values as slice only.

Comment: can you add more context? Usually, an empty slice is not represented as an empty string. Or maybe I am understanding you wrong, in which case you could try to explain it more.

Comment: So yea, basically I have an api, I need to make an internal validation in which if I pass `env: ""` it should throw an error that env should be given in this `env:[]` format if empty. 
I used if(len(Reg.Env)==0){ fmt.Println("env should be given in this `env:[]` format if empty")
Now the problem is when someone uses the correct format too the above `If` condition is executed rather then accepting the format.

Comment: @TheFool exactly an empty slice is not represented as an empty string so if someone tries to deliberately pass empty string in slice it should throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the error of `json.Unmarshal`, for example, you will know if the user passed invalid input.

```
var r struct { Env []string `json:"env"` }

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"env": ""}`), &r); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Produces this error message:

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field .env of type []string
```

https://go.dev/play/p/LozhJ14C7zj

---

The same happens when you use a decoder. I.e. from a http requests body.

```
var r struct { Env []string `json:"env"` }

dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(`{"env": ""}`))

if err := dec.Decode(&r); err != nil { fmt.Println(err) }
```

https://go.dev/play/p/_XpY3jquxVx

Comment: For the validation I used the JSON msg as 


```var r struct { Env []string `json:"env"` }

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"env": ""}`), &r); err == errors.New("json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field .env of type []string") {
    fmt.Println("Please provide input in slice format")
}```


So it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options depending on what do you need to send:

Case A:
`Reg{}` will be json-serialized to `{"env": null}`

Case B:
`Reg{Env: []string{} }` will be json-serialized to `{"env": []}`

Case C:
If `,omitempty` is added to the struct tag like this:

```
type Reg struct {
    Env []string `json:"env,omitempty"`
}
```

then `Reg{}` will be json-serialized to `{}`

See code example here: https://go.dev/play/p/lKI91VCoI0V